# How to assign default Values to Multiple select option in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created multiple select option drop-downs. Now I want to assign default selected values to the multiple select options. I have created code and it's working fine but the problem with the options value. I want id as a value in options.
javascript:-

```
 $scope.availableOptions = [{"client_id":"62024","client_name":"Advantage Land Co"},{"client_id":"59194","client_name":"Alpha - Brookings, SD"},{"client_id":"62413","client_name":"B and B Auto"},];
 $scope.simpli_client = {};
 $scope.simpli_client =["62024", "62413"];
```

and php code:-

```
<select id="multiSelect" class="ng-pristine ng-valid form-control" multiselect="" multiple="" ng-model="simpli_client" ng-options="option.client_id as option.client_name for option in availableOptions"></select>
```

It's working fine. Showing all the default values selected but I need client_id in option values. like this:-

```
<select id="multiSelect" class="ng-pristine ng-valid form-control" multiselect="" multiple="" ng-model="simpli_client" ng-options="option.client_id as option.client_name for option in availableOptions"><option value="62024" selected="selected">Advantage Land Co</option><option value="59194">Alpha - Brookings, SD</option><option value="62413" selected="selected">B and B Auto</option></select>
```

I need values in the option fields (value="62024").

Comment: `ng-options` creates `<option>` value and label. Why do you want to specify `<option>` tag explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xhph7qny/1/

You can use **track by** provided by angular ng-options.

HTML

```
<select id="multiSelect" class="ng-pristine ng-valid form-control" multiselect="" multiple="" ng-model="simpli_client" ng-options="option.client_id as option.client_name for option in availableOptions track by option.client_id"></select>
```

JS

```
$scope.simpli_client =[{"client_id":"62024","client_name":"Advantage Land Co"},{"client_id":"59194","client_name":"Alpha - Brookings, SD"}];
```

});

The only change is JS is that the ng-model should contain the entire objects rather than only client ids.